# Storing Objects in Linked List

Tags: java, list, object

I am creating a simple program which reads data from a text file and displays it in the console. The data that I am displaying is information regarding a student - name, id, subject, marks etc

The program reads the text file, and creates a student object for each user found. I am running into a problem when trying to store these students in a linked list. It seems to create a new list each time and overrides the previous one, so I always just end up with one student in the list.

How can I get it store them without overriding previous lists? Here is some of my code below:

```
public static boolean readFile(String filename) {
    File file = new File(filename);
    try {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
     String[] words = scanner.nextLine().split(",");

     int id = Integer.parseInt(words[0]);
     String firstName = words[1];
     String lastName = words[2];
     int mathMark1 = Integer.parseInt(words[3]);
     int mathMark2 = Integer.parseInt(words[4]);
     int mathMark3 = Integer.parseInt(words[5]);
     int englishMark1 = Integer.parseInt(words[6]);
     int englishMark2 = Integer.parseInt(words[7]);
     int englishMark3 = Integer.parseInt(words[8]);

     addStudent(id,firstName,lastName,mathMark1,mathMark2,mathMark3,englishMark1,englishMark2,englishMark3);
     }
    scanner.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("Failed to read file");
    }
     return true;
    }


private static void addStudent(int id, String firstName, String lastName,int
        mathsMark1, int mathsMark2, int mathsMark3, int englishMark1, int englishMark2,
        int englishMark3) {
    LinkedList<Student> student = new LinkedList<>();
    student.add(new Student(id,firstName,lastName));

    LinkedList<AssignmentMarks> mathematicsMarks = new LinkedList<>();
    mathematicsMarks.add(new AssignmentMarks("Mathematics",mathsMark1,mathsMark2,mathsMark3));

    LinkedList<AssignmentMarks> englishMarks = new LinkedList<>();
    englishMarks.add(new AssignmentMarks("English",englishMark1,englishMark2,englishMark3));
}
```

This code above is in my Main class. The code below is from my Student class:

```
public class Student {

    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private AssignmentMarks mathMarks;
    private AssignmentMarks englishMarks;

    public Student(int id, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return firstName;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks guys!

Comment: Create a linked list before you call the add method.

Comment: initiliaze linkedlist objects from outside of the addStudent method. for example; in readFile method

Comment: Yes, you have `LinkedList<Student> student = new LinkedList<>();` inside `addStudent`. So naturally a new one is created each time. You need to move that out of `addStudent` and pass the list to it as a parameter instead (or make it an instance member).

Comment: When asking for help, please take the time to format your code with consistent and relatively-standard bracing and indentation. (It's a good idea when not asking for help, too.)

Comment: Side note since you seem like you're at the beginning of your Java journey and it'll help to know: In *"It seems to create a new list each time and overrides the previous one..."* the word is *overwrite*, not *override*. "Override" is the word for when a subclass redefines a method it inherits from its parent or other ancestor. (There's also "overload," which is when you have more than one method with the same name, but different *signatures* [for instance, `void example()` and `void example(String x)`.)

Answer (score 2):

This variable

```
LinkedList<Student> student = new LinkedList<>();
```

needs to declared outside of the method, as a field, or within `readFile` and passed in as a parameter, otherwise it will be created everytime that you call `addStudent`

Answer (score 1):

Declare your `LinkedList` as a member of the class, because here every time you call `addStudent()` you are creating a new list.

You should instead do something like :

```
public class Test {

   private LinkedList<Student> student = new LinkedList<>();

   public static boolean readFile(String filename) {
      // ...
      addStudent(id,firstName,lastName,mathMark1,mathMark2,mathMark3,
                 englishMark1,englishMark2,englishMark3);

   }

   private static void addStudent(int id, String firstName, String lastName,int
        mathsMark1, int mathsMark2, int mathsMark3, int englishMark1, int englishMark2,
        int englishMark3) {
     // ...

     // this will now add it to the only instance of the list 
     student.add(new Student(id,firstName,lastName));
   }
}
```